How can I filter by `user.login` with Spring Data Elasticsearch and Spring Boot 3.2.5?
I’m trying to upgrade my 21-Points Health JHipster project from v7.9.4 to v8.4.0. The 7.9.4 version uses Elasticsearch Java 7 and the newer version uses Elasticsearch Java 8. I’m struggling to implement a boolean query that adds a filter by user.login. Here’s the existing code from v7:
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(queryStringQuery(query));
if (SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated() && !SecurityUtils.hasCurrentUserThisAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder.filter(matchQuery("user.login", SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElse("")));
}
Page<Points> page = pointsSearchRepository.search(queryBuilder, pageable);

And here’s the method in the repository it calls:
@Override
public Page<Points> search(QueryBuilder query, Pageable pageable) {
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(query).withPageable(pageable).build();
    return search(searchQuery);
}

How do I implement this in JHipster 8.4.0? Here's what I have that doesn't work:
if (SecurityUtils.isAuthenticated() && !SecurityUtils.hasCurrentUserThisAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)) {
    QueryVariant filterByUser = new MatchQuery.Builder()
        .field("user.login")
        .query(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElse(""))
        .build();
    BoolQuery.Builder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.bool();
    boolQueryBuilder.should(new Query(filterByUser));
    query = new Query(boolQueryBuilder.build()).toString();
}

The error is: Invalid query syntax!
Here’s the PointsSearchRepository.java:
package org.jhipster.health.repository.search;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.QueryStringQuery;
import java.util.List;
import org.jhipster.health.domain.Points;
import org.jhipster.health.repository.PointsRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHit;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHits;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;

/**
 * Spring Data Elasticsearch repository for the {@link Points} entity.
 */
public interface PointsSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Points, Long>, PointsSearchRepositoryInternal {}

interface PointsSearchRepositoryInternal {
    Page<Points> search(String query, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Points> search(Query query);

    @Async
    void index(Points entity);

    @Async
    void deleteFromIndexById(Long id);
}

class PointsSearchRepositoryInternalImpl implements PointsSearchRepositoryInternal {

    private final ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;
    private final PointsRepository repository;

    PointsSearchRepositoryInternalImpl(ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate, PointsRepository repository) {
        this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Points> search(String query, Pageable pageable) {
        NativeQuery nativeQuery = new NativeQuery(QueryStringQuery.of(qs -> qs.query(query))._toQuery());
        return search(nativeQuery.setPageable(pageable));
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Points> search(Query query) {
        SearchHits<Points> searchHits = elasticsearchTemplate.search(query, Points.class);
        List<Points> hits = searchHits.map(SearchHit::getContent).stream().toList();
        return new PageImpl<>(hits, query.getPageable(), searchHits.getTotalHits());
    }

    @Override
    public void index(Points entity) {
        repository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(entity.getId()).ifPresent(elasticsearchTemplate::save);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteFromIndexById(Long id) {
        elasticsearchTemplate.delete(String.valueOf(id), Points.class);
    }
}

One other thing I tried is using Spring Data to implement a findByUserLogin() method in the search repository. It doesn't work either. You can find that code in this PR.
I've tried using ChatGPT to solve this, but it keeps getting the imports wrong, so none of its suggestions work.

If you are using the old Rest High java API client, you should import from "org..." as here: https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/7.17.21/index.html  and if you want to use the new Java Api Client (Elasticsearch 8 and above) https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.13.4/index.html which starts with "co..." . Both libraries can coexist. It seems to be an import issue.

"One other thing I tried is using Spring Data to implement a findByUserLogin() method in the search repository. It doesn't work either." What error do you get here?
Besides that, I find it strange you create a query, then use the toString() method (does that return the correct query?) and then warp this in string query to pass it into a NativeQuery. Why not give the original query directly to the NativeQuery?
